# javascript seems to automatically detach event listeners from textareas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good afternoon dear community,

I wrote a web app (code below), that if you double click into it, it inserts a text area
into the frame.

If you double click the text area, it turns green, and by double clicking it again it turns white... (and so on)

The problem is, that if you create two or more text areas, only the most recently created one has the property of being toggleable. To me it seems that the last text areas are loosing their event handler(s) somehow.

How do I make the event handler(s) stay attached to every very text area?

Thanks in advance :)

[image: A screenshot of the problem]

```js
function randomIntInRange(min, max) { // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// Add a double click event listener to the root container
document.getElementById('root_container').addEventListener('dblclick', function(event) {
  var textArea = new TextArea();
  textArea.insertIntoHTML(event.clientX, event.clientY);
});

class TextArea {
  constructor() {
    // Generate a text area id
    this.id = randomIntInRange(1000000000, 9999999999);

    // Create a variable for changing the text area's bg-color in the onDoubleClick(event) method
    this.isToggled = false;
    this.onDoubleClick = this.onDoubleClick.bind(this);
  }

  insertIntoHTML(x, y) {
    // Insert a new text area into the html code
    document.getElementById('root_container').innerHTML += '<textarea id="' + this.id + '"></textarea>';

    // Setting the text area's position
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.left = x + 'px';
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.top = y + 'px';

    // Add a double click event listener to the text area
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener('dblclick', this.onDoubleClick);

    // Focus the text area
    document.getElementById(this.id).focus();
  }

  onDoubleClick(event) {
    // Prevent event bubbling
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    /* ******************************************
     *  Toggle the text area's background color
     * ****************************************** */
     
    // If the text area is not yet toggled
    if (!this.isToggled) {
      // Set the background color to green
      document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = '#7ce717';
      this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
    } else {
      // Otherwise to white
      document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = '#ffffffff';
      this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 200px;
}

#root_container {
  background-color: #797979;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Set the webpage's title -->
    <title>Web App</title>
    <!-- Include the cascading style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root_container">
    </div>
    <!-- Include the javascript file -->
    <script src="../javascript/behaviour.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An id cannot start with a number

Answer (score 0):

At this line :

`document.getElementById('root_container').innerHTML += '<textarea id="' + this.id + '"></textarea>';`

**You destroy the dom and the elements inside, and you reinject them.** Old TextAreas are deleted, and the events are detached.

Instead `innerHTML`, create an element and append it to your container with `appendChild`.

- [create an element with javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [inject an element inside another](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: @Juli , you can mark the question as “answered” ;-)